# why EF Core Tools need to invoke Program.CreateHostBuilder() to create a migration?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I have a asp.net core solution that consists of two project: api project and data access project

To be able to create a migration on data access project. I have to install `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design` on api project, and invoke commands like:

```
dotnet ef migrations add XXX --project pathToDataAccessProject.csproj --startup-project pathToApiProject.csproj
```

and I find an reference on "Design-time DbContext Creation"
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/cli/dbcontext-creation?tabs=dotnet-core-cli

I don't understand why EF Core Tools commands (for example, the Migrations commands) need to  obtain the service provider by invoking `Program.CreateHostBuilder()`, calling Build(), then accessing the Services property:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
        => CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();

    // EF Core uses this method at design time to access the DbContext
    public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args)
        => Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(
                webBuilder => webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>());
}

public class Startup
{
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        => services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>();

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
    }
}

public class ApplicationDbContext : DbContext
{
    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }
}
```

My understanding of migration is, EF tools only need to locate your DbContext (e.g. `ApplicationDbContext`) then look for its `DataSet<T>` table that you model classes map to, then EF tools are able to create a migration, why it needs to invoke `Program.CreateHostBuilder()`?

Answer (score 0):

To my understanding EF invokes Program.CreateHostBuilder() to make sure it has full application Context.
It sets up the configuration on a host for dependency injections and gives host access to configuration settings files like appsettings.json
it is to recreate the enviroment like it would be on runtime...
I think you cannot disable that and create migration without CreateHostBuilder()
Which is a pity if you know what you are doing

Comment: when you create a migration manually, you uses `dotnet ef migrations add XXX`  at compile time, I mean you don't start the api app then run the migration command. so do you mean `dotnet ef migrations add XXX`  runs the api app and after the migration is created it stops the app?

Comment: @user22155685 that is my understanding, i do not understand why it is required to runa  migration tho